# Allocating array of objects dynamically freeze

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

This is for an assignment before you tell me not to use an array. Unfortunately I have to.
I've troubleshot this for a good amount of time and I've finally given up and come to ask the smart people here. I know this is something to do with how I'm allocating the array, but I can't figure what's wrong. It goes through the inner loop once and then freeze on the second run. Sorry if I left anything important out. I will add any needed info.

Variables from Card

```
private:
    string *cardRank;
    string *suit;
    int rankNum;
    int value;
```

Problem Function

```
void initArray(Card **cPtr)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int index=0;

    cPtr = new Card*[DECK]; //deck is const int 52

for(i=0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(j=1; j < 14; ++j)
    {

        cPtr[index] = new Card(j, j, i); //freezes here. does not make  it to the first                               
                                         //function in the constructor
        cout << cPtr[index] << endl;
        ++index;

    }
}
}
```

Constructor

```
Card::Card(int cRank, int cValue, int suitNum)
{
    setRankNum(cRank);
    cout << "rank num set\n";
    setValue(cValue);
    cout << "val set\n";
    setSuit(suitNum);
    cout << "suit set\n";
    setRank(cRank);
    cout << "rank set\n";
}
```

Overloaded <<

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &strm, Card &aCard)
{
    strm << aCard.getRank() << " of " << aCard.getSuit();
    return strm;
}
```

whole program

```
#include <string>
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;

const int DECK = 52;

void initArray(Card **&cPtr);
void shufflePArray(Card **pArray);
void determineHand(Card **pArray);
bool isFlush(Card *hand);
bool isStraight(Card *hand);
bool isFour(Card *hand);
bool isThree(Card *hand);
bool isTwo(Card *hand);
void drawHand(Card *hand, Card **pArray);
void displayHand(Card **hand);

int main()
{
    Card **cArray;
    initArray(cArray);
    cout << "done.";
    shufflePArray(cArray);
    determineHand(cArray);


    delete [] cArray;
    return 0;
}


void initArray(Card **&cPtr)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int index=0;

    cPtr = new Card*[DECK];

    for(i=0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for(j=1; j < 13; ++j)
        { cout << "inner loop " << index << endl;

        cPtr[index] = new Card(j, j, i);
        cout << cPtr[index] << endl;
        ++index;
        }
    }
}
void shufflePArray(Card **pArray)
{
    //code here
}
void determineHand(Card ***pArray)
{
    Card hand[5];
    drawHand(hand, pArray);
    displayHand(pArray);

    if (isFlush(hand) == true)
    {
        if(isStraight(hand) == true)
            cout << "Straight flush!!!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "You got a flush!" << endl;
    }
    else if(isStraight(hand) == true)
    {
        cout << "You got a straight!" << endl;
    }
    else if(isFour(hand) == true)
    {
        cout << "Four of a kind!!!" << endl;
    }
    else if(isThree(hand)==true)
    {
        cout << "Three of a kind!" << endl;
    }
    else if(isTwo(hand) == true)
    {
        cout << "That's a pair";
    }
}
bool isFlush(Card *hand)
{

    int i;
    int match;

    for (i=0; i<5;++i)
    {
        if (hand[0].getSuit() == hand[i].getSuit())
            match++;
    }

    if (match == 5)
       return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool isStraight(Card *hand)
{
    int match;

    for (int i=0; i<5;++i)
    {
        if (hand[0].getValue() == hand[i].getValue() - 1)
            match++;
    }

    if (match == 5)
       return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool isFour(Card *hand)
{
    int match = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        match=0;
        for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
        {
            if (hand[i] == hand[j])
                match++;
            if (match == 4)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
bool isThree(Card *hand)
{
    int match = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        match=0;
        for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
        {
            if (hand[i] == hand[j])
                match++;
            if (match == 3)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
bool isTwo(Card *hand)
{
    int match = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        match=0;
        for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
        {
            if (hand[i] == hand[j])
                match++;
            if (match == 2)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}

void drawHand(Card *hand, Card **pArray)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5;++i)
     cout << hand[i];
    }
}
    {
        hand[i] = *pArray[i];
    }
}

void displayHand(Card **hand)
{
    Card temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
```

contents of card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class Card
{
    private:
        string *cardRank;
        string *suit;
        int rankNum;
        int value;
    public:
        Card();
        Card(int cRank, int cValue, int suitNum);
        friend ostream &operator << (ostream &strm, Card &aCard);
        bool operator > (const Card &aCard);
        bool operator < (const Card &aCard);
        bool operator == (const Card &aCard);
        void setRank(int r);
        void setSuit(int s);
        void setValue(int v);
        void setRankNum(int n);
        string getRank();
        string getSuit();
        int getRankNum();
        int getValue();
};

#endif // CARD_H
```

contents of Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Card::Card()
{
    cardRank = NULL;
    suit = NULL;
    rankNum = 0;
    value = 0;
}


Card::Card(int cRank, int cValue, int suitNum)
{
    setRankNum(cRank);
    cout << "rank num set\n";
    setValue(cValue);
    cout << "val set\n";
    setSuit(suitNum);
    cout << "suit set\n";
    setRank(cRank);
    cout << "rank set\n";
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &strm, Card &aCard)
{
    strm << aCard.getRank() << " of " << aCard.getSuit();
    return strm;
}

bool Card::operator > (const Card &aCard)
{
    if (aCard.value > value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Card::operator < (const Card &aCard)
{
    if (aCard.value < value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Card::operator == (const Card &aCard)
{
    if (value == aCard.value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Card::setRank(int r)
{
    switch(r)
    {
    case 13:
        *cardRank = "Ace";
    case 1:
        *cardRank = "Two";
    case 2:
        *cardRank = "Three";
    case 3:
        *cardRank = "Four";
    case 4:
        *cardRank = "Five";
    case 5:
        *cardRank = "Six";
    case 6:
        *cardRank = "Seven";
    case 7:
        *cardRank = "Eight";
    case 8:
        *cardRank = "Nine";
    case 9:
        *cardRank = "Ten";
    case 10:
        *cardRank = "Jack";
    case 11:
        *cardRank = "Queen";
    case 12:
        *cardRank = "King";
    }
}

void Card::setSuit(int s)
{
    if(s==0){
        *suit = "Hearts";
        cout << "suit set";}
    else if(s==1)
        *suit = "Diamonds";
    else if (s==2)
        *suit = "Clubs";
    else if (s==3)
        *suit = "Spades";
    else
        cout << "Invalid suit num.";
}
void Card::setValue(int v)
{
    if (v > 0)
        value = v;
}
void Card::setRankNum(int n)
{
    rankNum = n;
}
string Card::getRank()
{
    return *cardRank;
}
string Card::getSuit()
{
    return *suit;
}
int Card::getRankNum()
{
    return rankNum;
}
int Card::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Card **&cPtr  ===> what is that oO

Comment: Instead of disjoint bits and pieces of code, put together a small but full working example that demonstrates the error.  No one knows when, where, or how "initArray" is called.

Comment: Why are cardRank and suit pointers in your Card class?  I know you need to code a dynamic array, but I think you're going overboard pointerizing everything like this.  The cardRank and suit can be non-pointer std::string members.

Comment: @lloyd - There are critical pieces of information missing from your post.  First, what is the implementation of getSuit() and getRank()?  Second, where, when, and how do you initialize the cardRank and suit pointers?  Do you use these pointers in the operator << function?  If these pointers do play a role, then do as I suggested -- get rid of the pointers and make them std::string objects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's part of the assignment. our instructor likes to emphasize pointers.  Also the getSuit() and getRank() functions just returns the string pointed to by suit and rank pointers. I've added these to the code to see for yourself.

Comment: Post a **complete** example that people can compile. It should also be as **minimal** as you can make it. Probably it only has to instantiate a single `Card`.

Comment: @lloyd - `our instructor likes to emphasize pointers. ` and bingo, there is your error.  If you just did what I suggested, even temporarily, you may have seen that your program working.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason for your troubles is that you are dereferencing a NULL pointer:

```
void Card::setRank(int r)
{
    switch(r)
    {
        case 13:
          *cardRank = "Ace";
        case 1:
          *cardRank = "Two";
     //...
```

The cardRank is NULL.  You now try to dereference a NULL pointer.  Unless I missed something, where is the call to "cardRank = new std::string;"?

But that brings up a bigger point -- in your comment you stated that your professor wants you to use pointers.  But honestly, there is no reason whatsoever to use pointers for those string members -- absolutely none.

You do need pointers to implement your dynamic array, but that's it.  Either you are reading the professor's intentions incorrectly, or the professor needs to get another profession.

Comment: I know there's no reason to use pointers. But yeah that's basically it. I forgot to allocate memory for the pointers. I added that allocation to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a pointer to a pointer as value in : `initArray(Card **cPtr)`, apparently your intention is to change it (i.e return the allocated `Card` array.

I cannot really say what is happening exactly but some memory gets overwritten, the return address in the stack probably

Anyway either change it to reference i.e. `initArray(Card **&cPtr)` or use `initArray(Card ***cPtr)` and change the code accordingly.

The second problem in the use of strings, change `string *cardRank` to `string cardRank` and suit as well, you don't need pointers to strings (it's not like `char*`, those are objects any way, the assignments should be changed from `*cardRank = "Ace"` to `cardRank = "Ace"`

Comment: Thanks. I had it like that originally with the reference but the same error unfortunately.

Comment: The error is caused by the incorrect usage of string, as mentioned in the second answer (the `=` operator is overloaded for strings, and yours are `NULL`, see my suggestion